# extract string after the first special character

Tags: java, regex

I have this string below:

```
foob/site?article=foo-title&id=12
```

how can I get the `foo-title` from the above string using regex?
A short solution would be appreciated.

*Note*: the `foo-title` could be any title.

Comment: What language/platform are you using for regex?

Comment: I'm using java, actually its possible to do this via some lines of code, but I want to acheive this as short as possible, e.g; ([a-z0-9]+)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will work:

```
(?<=article=)[^&]++(?=&)
```

- `(?<=article=)` positive lookbehind for "article="
- `[^&]++` match everything that isn't an "&", possessively
- `(?=&)` positive lookahead for "&"

Here is an example is Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "foob/site?article=foo-title&id=12";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=article=)[^&]++(?=&)");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Java supports positive lookbehinds so you could use:

```
(?<=article=)[^&]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Javascript works for you but here is how you do in most of other regex platforms also:

```
var s = 'foob/site?article=foo-title&id=12';
r = s.replace(/^[^=]+=([^&]+).*$/, '$1');
//=> foo-title
```

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment here is Java code:

```
String r = "oob/site?article=foo-title&id=12".replaceAll("^[^=]+=([^&]+).*$", "$1");
//=> foo-title
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should do:

```
article=([^&]+)&
```

Title will be assigned to group 1. Sample usage in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("article=([^&]+)&");
Matcher m = p.matcher("foob/site?article=foo-title&id=12");
if (m.find()) {
    String title = m.group(1);
    // process the title
}
```

Comment: Would this fail to match if there is no & specified in the url?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
"article=(.*?)&"
```

Comment: would this fail to match if there is no & specified in the url?